# Java Base Class Reference Variable

Tags: java, class, variables, reference, radix

*A base class reference variable may be assigned the address of either a base class object or a derived class object.*

True/False?

Can anybody show me an example of what this means? I'm new to Java and am trying to understand language specific terms of Java. Thanks.

I think an example of this would be the code I've written below:

```
public class B extends A {
    A a = new A();
    A ab = new B();
}

class A {

}
```

I think that since both reference variables are valid syntax (in Eclipse) then the answer is true.

Comment: What did your research reveal?

Comment: We don't know what you don't know?  What part are you having trouble with?

Comment: I'm not sure what a derived class object is. I know what a base class is though. I think it means a class that extends another.

Comment: Lets say we have `class Base{}` and `class Derived extends Base{}`. Question is: "is something like `Base b1 = new Base()` and `Base b2 = new Derived()` valid in Java?".

Comment: It's the basis for IS-A inheritance and polymorphism.

Comment: I have updated my post with an example of what you said @Pshemo. It seems that both are valid Java syntax as Eclipse is not throwing an error. So it seems that the answer is True?

Comment: If you're precise, the answer is "False". Assigning the adresses of objects is not the only option. `null` can be assigned to any reference variable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> A base class reference variable may be assigned the address of either a base class object or a derived class object.
>
> True/False?

True, because all derived class object is an instance of the base class, but not the other way round.

> Can anybody show me an example of what this means? I'm new to Java and am trying to understand language specific terms of Java. Thanks.

First of all, you need to know what is a base class and a derived class.

Base class also known as parent class or super class is a class which is extended by another. A simple example would be `Animal class`.

While a child class extends from its super class. For example, `Lion class`.

We know that all lions are animals. But not all animals are essentially lions.
The subclass is just a subset of the superclass.

Hence, when we have a base class reference, we are allowed to assign derived class object into it.

**Example:**

```
class Animal{
    
}

class Lion extends Animal{

}


Animal someAnimal = new Lion(); //because all lions are animals
```

However, the reverse is untrue. Thus not possible and not allowed in Java:

```
Lion lion = new Animal(); //not allowed in Java.
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have a superclass named `Parent`

```
public class Parent {
    // ...
}
```

and a derived/subclass named `Child`

```
public class Child extends Parent {
    // ...
}
```

then *a base class reference* refers to any variable defined as `Parent pObj` (here the name `pObj` doesn't matter), *a base class object* refers to an object created as `new Parent()` and *a derived class object* refers to one created as `new Child()`.

So, the following

> A base class reference variable may be assigned the address of either a base class object or a derived class object.

refers to an assignment like

```
Parent pObj = new Child();
```

What's the benefit of this you may ask? It's *polymorphism*. The subclass can *override* the superclass methods to redefine behaviour. This lets the `pObj` reference respond differently to the same method call depending on whether `pObj` points to a `Parent()` or a `Child()` object.

You may find it a bit difficult to grasp the benefits but take a look on Object-oriented programming esp. *polymorphism* and *inheritance* and your understanding will get better.

Answer (score 0):

```
class Base {
}
 
class Derived extends Base {
}
 
class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Base x = new Base();   // Correct
        Base y = new Derived(); // Correct
        Derived z = new Derived(); // Correct
    }
}
```

Assigning a derived class reference to a base class reference is allowed in Java.